# cocoa-Why my ViewController can't load NSWindow object in the corresponding nib file?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSViewController` and a corresponding `.xib` file.
In the nib file, there's a `NSPanel`.
I link the `NSPanel` to the ViewController:

`@property (strong) IBOutlet NSPanel *panel;`

However, when I wanted to pass `panel` to my `AppDelegate` and show on screen, my code didn't work well.
This is part of my code:

```
//MainViewController.m
-(NSPanel *)passPanel{
    if(!self.panel){
        NSLog(@"panel is nil");
        self.panel = [[NSPanel alloc] init];    //breakpoint
        return self.panel;    
    }else{
        NSLog(@"panel is not nil");
    return self.panel;    //breakpoint
    }
}

//AppDelegate.m
MainViewController* vc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
self.window = [vc passPanel];
```

I think when I initiate `vc`, the panel should be initiate as what it's like in the nib file because I've set it as a property.

But why it is always `nil`? 
I've also set breakpoints to debug, I found it not working as I wanted.

In order not to make the question seem confusing, I paste all my code in `MainViewController.m` below:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()


@end

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize panel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do view setup here.
}

-(NSPanel*)passPanel{
    NSLog(@"passing panel to sender...");
    if(!self.panel){
        NSLog(@"panel is nil");
        self.panel = [[NSPanel alloc] init];
        return self.panel;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"panel is not nil");
    return self.panel;
    }
}
@end
```

**EDIT**

As the code doesn't show clear about the question, I put some screenshots below.

`MainMenu.xib`

[image]

`MainViewController.xib`

[image]

The `MainMenu.xib` is the default nib file created when the project is created. In this nib file I have a `window` to show other views. In the `MainViewController.xib`, I have a `NSPanel` which is a subclass of `NSWindow`. Actually I'm not sure it's proper to use a ViewController(`MainViewController`) to control a window. Now I want to show this `NSPanel` object. So I assign this panel to my `window` in `MainMenu.xib`. It did work(although I felt it's not a good way).
My question is, I think after the window is assigned a `NSPanel`, the panel would automatically load its view. However, it didn't.
In the `passPanel` method, it turned out that `self.view` is `nil`. So what appear on screen is a blank window.

What I want it to show:
[image]

but it shows
[image]

Comment: Where are you going with a series of seemingly similar questions?  Yesterday, I asked you what you meant by 'view.'  You ignored it and deleted the question.  You now post another similar question.  Why do you insist on using NSViewController?

Comment: Have you actually go through my question today? In fact I think my question is clear enough, or if you don't understand what the question is you can ask me to fix it. Why do you just stick on what I ask but not how to solve it? As there was no answers, I referred some tutorials and solved my previous question on NSView. Here my question is not about NSView anymore. And you ask me why I insist on using NSViewController, I'm quite new to cocoa and objective-c programming. Without much experiences, how can I figure out what is the best choice?

Comment: No, your intentions are not clear.  I don't know the best choice - the best choice for what?

Comment: What I want to do is just show some views on the screen. I have several nib file and I can't load views of these nib files properly. This is my question. I don't know what I **should** use instead of `NSViewController`.

Comment: WHAT IS A VIEW?  An instance of NSView placed over a window (NSWindow) or a panel (NSPanel)?  Why don't you post a screenshot to make it clear?

Comment: I admit this is my fault not to post some screenshots to make it straight forward. I've edited the question. :)

Comment: Don't use NSViewController or NSWindowController unless you really have to.

Comment: OK. I'll go get some demos and have a try. But Why? I think if I follow the MVC pattern, then it's better to have a NSViewController to control the view?